# me toca Mostar los alumnos con notas superiores a la media. pero no se optener los indicesen en los que se repite

Tags: python

este codigo tengo que nostrar el nombre de los alumnos que su nota es superior a la media  pero no se como concegir los indices y se repite la nota.

```
 numeroDeNotas=int(input('por favor ingrese el numero de alumnos para calcular su nota ')) 
    numeroDeNotas-=1
    alumnos=[] 
    notas= []
    posicion =0
    while posicion<= numeroDeNotas:
        alumno= input('por favor ingrese el nombre de los alumnos ')
        alumnos.append(alumno)
        nota=float(input('por favor ingrese la nota del alumno '))
        notas.append(nota)
        posicion+=1
    
    promedio= sum(notas)/ len(notas)
    print(f'el promedio de notas es {promedio} ') 
    for x in notas :    
        if x > promedio:
         indice= notas.index(x)
         print(f'el estudiante que supera la nota de la media es {alumnos[indice]} con {x} ')
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

estuve probando tu codigo en un playground de python (https://www.online-python.com/KXmLvup8J6) donde saque los input por consola y hardcodie un poco el codigo para que funcione en ese entorno con valores fijos.

Hasta donde ví, no hay errores de sintaxis o logicos. Pero hay dos cosas que no entiendo, primero, cual seria el problema? y segundo porque le restas -1 al valor que ingresa el usuario.

Te dejo el codigo con el que probé por si queres hacer vos una prueba:

```
numeroDeNotas=5
    
alumnos=['Antonio', 'Javier', 'Lara', 'Eliot', 'Maria', 'Jhon'] 
notas= []
posicion =0
while posicion<= numeroDeNotas:
    nota=float(posicion*5)
    notas.append(nota)
    posicion+=1

promedio= sum(notas)/ len(notas)
print(f'el promedio de notas es {promedio} ') 

print(notas)
for x in notas :    
    if x > promedio:
     indice= notas.index(x)
     print(f'el estudiante que supera la nota de la media es {alumnos[indice]} con {x} ')
```

Y otra alternativa un poco mejor a mi criterio es que lo hagas con diccionarios, pero no se si la consigna de tu tarea es hacerlo si o si con dos arrays. Si vos tenes libertad de como hacerlo podrias intentar esto:

```
numeroDeNotas=5
    
alumnos=['Antonio', 'Javier', 'Lara', 'Eliot', 'Maria', 'Jhon'] 
dic = {}
posicion =0
while posicion<= numeroDeNotas:
    nota=float(posicion*5)
    dic[alumnos[posicion]] = nota
    posicion+=1

promedio= sum(notas)/ len(notas)
print(f'el promedio de notas es {promedio} ') 

print(dic)
for clave in dic:
    if(dic[clave] > promedio):
        print(f'el estudiante que supera la nota de la media es {clave} con {dic[clave]} ')
```

como podes ver solo al array de alumnos lo uso para llenar las claves del diccionario pero vos tendrias que poner el input de la consola. Si podes usar el diccionario podemos ver como hacer esa parte pero no seria muy diferente.

En ambos casos me dieron los mismos resultados. Y tambien el posicion * 5 es simplemente para tener otros numeros pero ahi tambien seria la nota que ingresa el usuario